# How to open a winform at same location and with same size of its parent in vb.net? Parent may be Winform or UserControl

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim popCus As New PopCustomer()
popCus.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
popCus.Location = New Point(ctrList.Location)
popCus.Size = New Size(ctrList.Size)
popCus.ShowDialog()
```

Here ctrList is a UserControl's object and PopCustomer if a Winform.
   I want open PopCustomer at same location and same size of ctrList.

Answer (score 1):

The problem there is that the `Location` of the `UserControl` is relative to its own parent while for the form it's relative to the screen.

If you change this:

```
popCus.Location = New Point(ctrList.Location)
```

to this:

```
popCus.Location = ctrList.PointToScreen(Point.Empty)
```

then you'll get the effect you want.  You can actually use the same code for a form so that means that you can write a single method with a `Control` parameter and then use that parameter to set the `Location` and `Size` of the new form.  You can then call that method and pass either a form or a user control as an argument.